# Align multiple equations centering

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to center multiple equations with align, gather, and center but could have done yet. How can I do it? The picture shows what I want. Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Delta l_{x}|_{x=l_x} = 0.001l_x 
\Delta l_{x}|_{x=0} = \Delta l_{y}|_{y=l_y} = \Delta l_{y}|_{y=0} = \Delta l_{z}|_{z=z} = \Delta l_{z}|_{z=0} =0
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Use `gathered` or `gather` depending whether you want a shared equation number

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}

equation
\begin{equation}
  \begin{gathered}
\Delta l_{x}|_{x=l_x} = 0.001l_x \\
\Delta l_{x}|_{x=0} = \Delta l_{y}|_{y=l_y} = \Delta l_{y}|_{y=0} = \Delta l_{z}|_{z=z} = \Delta l_{z}|_{z=0} =0    
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

gather
\begin{gather}
\Delta l_{x}|_{x=l_x} = 0.001l_x \\
\Delta l_{x}|_{x=0} = \Delta l_{y}|_{y=l_y} = \Delta l_{y}|_{y=0} = \Delta l_{z}|_{z=z} = \Delta l_{z}|_{z=0} =0
\end{gather}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You should also suggest reading the user guide (`texdoc amsldoc`).  It's not all that long.

Comment: Thank you so much David. I will check the guide. Have a nice day.